# Code snippet not getting highlighted

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, code

I have a piece of code after a list in a question. It is not getting syntax highlighted, even if I use SO code block, or indent it myself.

If I move it before the list, it works as expected. Also, if I use backticks (`), then it highlights the code.

[FileSystemWatcher: Ignore first change to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55820526/5192528)

The code is the last three lines, right in the end.

Comment: The list is preventing proper formatting. One solution, but an HTML comment in between, `<?-- -->`  (as I have done for you)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that was quick :-)

Comment: Another solution -- indent it more, so that it is indented code that is part of the list.

Comment: Thanks @Hovercraft, that was quick. What did you change? I don't understand from the diff itself.

Comment: @AkshayKhot See: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55820526/revisions, and click "side-by-side markdown"

Comment: @AkshayKhot: open the edit view to see what I did

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The revisions you mean...

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys! Is this a bug in the editor, or do I need to keep this trick in mind whenever I want to add code snippet after a list?

Comment: Actually, opening the edit view worked as well! It shows the html comment. @U9-Forward.

Comment: @AkshayKhot Yup, regarding first comment, it's not a trick, just don't add the funny thing again...

Comment: Not sure I understand. What funny thing?

Comment: @AkshayKhot <?-- -->

Comment: Okay, so just indent it more, as the third comment suggests above?

Comment: If it is supposed to be part of the list, then indent 8 spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in a list that is part of a list:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2 with code

   ```
   public void main(String[] args) {
       // Code indented 8 spaces, not 4
   }
   ```
3. Item 3 without code

---

Code that is after a list, put in a separator, such as an HTML comment, `<!-- -->`

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3

```
// Separator, <!-- -->, is above this line but not shown
public void main(String[] args) {
    // Code indented 4 spaces, not 8
}
```

Comment: That is not the proper syntax for an HTML comment. You need an exclamation mark, not a question mark. `<!--  -->`

Comment: @CodyGray: oops, and darn. Need to brush up on my HTML! Thankfully the site is forgiving

Comment: The really sad thing is, you just got corrected on your HTML syntax by a C++ programmer. ;-)

Comment: Oh, the shame!!!